# MVC Kendo Grid server side filter by Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I'm new at Kendo MVC, trying to build an application but at client side I'm using Javascript instead of conventional RAZOR.

I'm getting and loading data properly in the grid but facing problem while filtering. I'm using this code:

```
$("#gridStudent").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: {
        type: "json",
        transport: {
            read: '../Student/GetStudentData/',
        },
        pageSize: 20,
        serverPaging: true,
        serverFiltering: true,
        serverSorting: true,
        },
    columns: [
            { field: "StudentId", title: "StudentId", width: 50, hidden: true },
            { field: "StudentName", title: "Student Name", width: "130px" },
            { field: "Mobile", title: "Mobile", width: "130px" },
            { field: "Gender", title: "Gender", template: '#=Gender == 2 ? "Female" : "Male"#', width: "130px" },
            { field: "Section", title: "Section", width: "130px" },
            { field: "Address", title: "Address", width: "130px" }
    ],
    pageable: {
        refresh: true,
        serverPaging: true,
        serverFiltering: true,
        serverSorting: true
    },
    filterable: true,
    sortable: true,
   navigatable: true,
    selectable: "row"
});
```

And controller is

```
   public JsonResult GetStudentData([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest options)
{
 var query= _Db.Students.ToList();
 var data = query.ToDataSourceResult(options);
 return Json(data , JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

This loading data to grid perfectly but while filtering, I'm not getting filtered data object

[image: Filtering From Grid]
[image]

Please suggest me some solution on this. I'm going to use javascript/jQuery (no razor) in client side so please something in this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this happen on every column? 

I set up Telerik's [grid example](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/index) to be similar to your code in [this example](http://dojo.telerik.com/IfEyE), but the filters are still working. Take a look at that example and see if you can see something you're missing outside of your grid.

Comment: Yes, this is happing for every column. I've used " parameterMap: function (options) {---}" for test then i've found  "skip,take,page,pageSize,sort,filter" in options  but I'need in "Aggregates,Filters,Groups,Page,PageSize,Sorts" manner, I've also changed the name befor send it to server but "Aggregates and Sorts" not working.

Comment: Do filters need to be applied server side? There are lots of examples available for [client-side filtering](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/filter-menu-customization) which can also be customised to your requirements

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I needed server side because my transaction will happen for lot of data (possibility of 100k). So, for increasing performance i really needed that.